# Unable to render Chinese or Korean characters in itext htmltopdf convert

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, itext

I have a HTML String with Chinese or Korean characters. I want to convert the HTML to PDF using itextpdf.html2pdf, but after conversion I am not able to see Chinese or Korean characters in pdf file.

Below is the code snippet:

```
RestTemplate rTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpMessageConverter<String> sMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverter = Lists.newArrayList();
httpMessageConverter.add(sMessageConverter);
rTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverter);
String d = rTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(d, "utf-8");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(document.html(), outputArray);
return outputArray.toByteArray();
```

Sample HTML content:

```
<html> 
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <p><span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">長空</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman,serif">(Broken Sword),</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">秦王殘劍</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman,serif">(Flying Snow),</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">飛雪</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman,serif">(Moon), </span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">如月</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman,serif">(the King), and</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">秦王</span> <span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman,serif">(Sky).</span></p> 
  <p style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family:Batang">빈집</p> 
  <p>Test</p>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Pdf output:
[image]

I have read that we need to embed the FONT to the PDF to get the Unicode characters to show up on PDF.

I tried using:

```
BaseFont bff = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = FontFactory.getFont(AsianFontMapper.ChineseSimplifiedFont, AsianFontMapper.ChineseTraditionalEncoding_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

But it's not allow me to add  `com.lowagie.text Font` object into `com.itextpdf.layout.font FontSelector` , also I saw one testpdf package font-asian but not sure how to use in my code base.

Can someone please suggest the solution. Or if I am missing something in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different things. BaseFont class cannot be used in iText 7 because it is a part of different version of iText and it's not compatible with pdfHTML iText 7. In order to use or set the fonts correctly in pdfHTML, you need to make the use of FontProvider class in pdfHTML. Please refer to the knowledge base link of iText https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-in-pdfhtml that explains how fonts works in pdfHTML and what code to be used.

```
public static final String FONT = "src/main/resources/fonts/cardo/Cardo- 
Regular.ttf";
public void createPdf(String src, String font, String dest) throws IOException {
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT);
fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest), properties);
```

}